# How can I get the on screen keyboard for flutter web apps running on a touch screen

Tags: flutter, keyboard, flutter-web

I am building flutter for the web, and I want to use it on a touch screen.  My app runs great and takes input from the mouse, but when I want to use a text input field the app works with the physical keyboard that I have attached since I'm running in chrome on my Macbook.  I would like to use this web app on a touch screen kiosk type of setup though so I wanted to always bring up the virtual (on screen) keyboard for text entry.

I tried:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.show');
    super.initState();
  }
```

And this does force open the virtual keyboard if I run on a virtual tablet for example, but didn't work for me when I ran the exact same flutter app in chrome.

I'm running with v1.9.1+hotfix.3-pre.1, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G103

Does Anyone know a way to force flutter to always use virtual on screen keyboard?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32763 makes me think my issue is related to the fact that flutter "knows" that I'm on a PC and have a keyboard.  So maybe this will work if I'm on a touch screen with no keyboard plugged in?  How does flutter know there is a physical keyboard or not?

Comment: You can use https://pub.dev/packages/virtual_keyboard_multi_language package for on screen keyboard

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a native function in Flutter to invoke the desktop virtual keyboard. As a workaround you can either use [virtual_keybaord_multi_language](https://pub.dev/packages/virtual_keyboard_multi_language) plugin that creates a keyboard within the app or you can [enable the virtual keyboard by default](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-the-on-screen-keyboard-osk-to-type-ecbb5e08-5b4e-d8c8-f794-81dbf896267a) on the device. If you're running on Windows, [switching to tablet mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-tablet-mode-on-or-off-add3fbce-5cb5-bf76-0f9c-8d7b30041f30) should automatically invoke the softkeyboard when a TextField is active.

Edit: This seems to be a valid use case, you can track the feature request on this [ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109546).